# How a Thread object's run method internally calls Runnable object's run method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know how the run() method of Thread class calls the Runnable object's run method internally, or is there anything else that calls the run() method of Runnable object

I have read and understood that when we create a Thread object using the constructor Thread(Runnable target), then the run() method of that target object is executed. But the implementation of run() method of Thread class is empty.So, if we try to call the run() method on the Thread object, how does it internally calls the run() method of the target object?

```
class T1 implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

System.out.print(" " + i);

}
}

}

class T2 implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {

System.out.print(" " + i);

}

}

}

public class MainTh {

public static void main(String[] args) {

T1 ta = new T1();
T2 tb = new T2();
Thread t1 = new Thread(ta);
Thread t2 = new Thread(tb);

t1.run();
t2.run();
}

}
```

This is the output I am getting, which is correct according to documentation of run() method of Thread class: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `Thread.run()` is this ([source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6d98a3bdd8e0097b0a1549f6c42511d7429df766/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L828)):

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Can you guess what `target` is? It's a `Runnable` you can set in the constructor.

So `run()` either executes the `Runnable` given to the thread during construction, or whatever code there's in `run()`, which means that you can write a class that `extends Thread`, and override its `run()` method:

```
public class MyThred extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Foo!");
    }
}
```